# Uncaught HierarchyRequestError

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm a beginner with dart and polymer. When I run the web app in Chrome I get:

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'HTML' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'. patches-mdv.js:57
(anonymous function) patches-mdv.js:57
(anonymous function) patches-mdv.js:57
(anonymous function) patches-mdv.js:57
```

The appendChild is probably in generated dart2js code, namely in the following piece:

```dart
  Node: {
    "^": "EventTarget;ownerDocument=,text:textContent=",
    remove$0: function(receiver) {
      var t1 = receiver.parentNode;
      if (t1 != null)
        J._removeChild$1$x(t1, receiver);
    },
    toString$0: function(receiver) {
      var t1 = receiver.nodeValue;
      return t1 == null ? J.Interceptor.prototype.toString$0.call(this, receiver) : t1;
    },
    append$1: function(receiver, newChild) {
      return receiver.appendChild(newChild);
    },
    insertBefore$2: function(receiver, newChild, refChild) {
      return receiver.insertBefore(newChild, refChild);
    },
    _removeChild$1: function(receiver, oldChild) {
      return receiver.removeChild(oldChild);
    },
    _replaceChild$2: function(receiver, newChild, oldChild) {
      return receiver.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
    },
    $isNode: true,
    "%": "DocumentType|Notation;Node"
  },
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said on https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web/bgMajiu_iR4/rygd5Ftk668J, from the symptoms, it looks like platform.js has been loaded twice.

So remove the following two lines from every html except your toplevel index.html:

```
<script src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
<script src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
```

Update:
With Polymer > 0.14.0 `platform.js` is not necessary anymore. It is added automatically by `pub build` and `pub serve`.